# delete a variable out of scope

Tags: c++

```
int* func()
{
   int* i=new int[1];
   //do something
   return i; 
}

void funcc()
{
   int* tmp=func();
   //delete allocated memory after use
   delete tmp;
}
```

should delete working as described in the second function be a correct use ?
I think I didn't allocate memory to it by new ? new was used in the first, to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have stated, you should use `delete[]` to delete arrays, not `delete`.

But, if you're asking whether it's okay to delete `tmp` because the memory it points to wasn't allocated with `new`, then your premise is incorrect.

It *was* allocated with `new`. The address of the memory that you allocate within the function for `i` is passed back to be stored in `tmp`, so it *does* point to memory that was allocated by `new`.

You're correct that `i` itself is out of scope at that point but memory allocated by `new` survives the scope change on exit from the function. And, since you're storing its location into `tmp`, you still have access to it.

Hence the deletion (once you make it an array deletion with `[]`) is quite valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes sense, the repeated use of a different variable is definitely allowed since it still points to the previous one. :-D

Comment: @Tomalak, that's possibly more detail han desired by the OP but I've adjusted the text to clarify.

Comment: paxdiablo: Still, teaching misinterpretations isn't desired by _anyone_ ;)

Answer (score 7):

It should be `delete [] tmp;` because you're doing array new, but otherwise, it's correct.

Comment: Indeed. The first part of your answer points out a major flaw; I believe the second part addresses the concern that the OP actually had.

Comment: Thank you, Tomalak and Russell

Answer (score 3):

This is Undefined Behaviour™. You can *only* use `delete` if you used `new`. If you used `new[]`, you MUST `delete[]` it. More than that, this is hideously unsafe code- you need a smart pointer.

Comment: A smart pointer for a dynamically-allocated array? Pull the other one! Vectorise or stigmatise.

Comment: Ok thanks, I vote you up, see my next question in Nawaz's comment section.

Comment: @Tomalak: `unique_ptr` has a `T[]` specialization. @Baby Dolphin: Post another question if you have another question.

Answer (score 3):

No. `new T[]` should match `delete []t`. And `new T` should match `delete t`. Otherwise, your code would invoke undefined bevavior.

And it doesn't matter if you do `delete []tmp` outside the function. Its okay to do so. All that you need to keep in mind that the *form* of delete.

Comment: Thanks, I was incorrect it should be `delete []tmp`. But should deleting a temp that I had not allocated memory with be correct ? I think new-delete pair should be applied on the same defined variable.

Answer (score 3):

- My spidey-senses tell me that you're wondering whether the dynamically-allocated `int` that you create in `func` is the same one that you attempt to `delete` in `funcc`.

  The answer is: yes. Although you don't use strictly the same pointer variable, both pointers point to the *same object*.
- **However**, please remember to use `delete[]` (with the `[]`) when you used `new[]` (with the `[]`). Your code is broken until you fix this.

---

Also, try to avoid `new`ing in one place and `delete`ing in another. Perhaps consider a `std::vector` instead, which is far less error-prone.